# What does "no selector" mean?

Tags: ada

I am getting the following compiler error:

> no selector "Put_Timestamp" for type "Timestamp_Record_Type" defined at time_types.ads:99

The line of code giving the error is:

```
Timestamp.Put_Timestamp(Trs_Time);
```

The Timestamp and Time_Types packages in this project is imported at the top of the same file the error is in:

```
with Timestamp;
with Time_Types;
```

And timestamp.ads contains the following:

```
with Ada.Calendar;

with Time_Types;


package Timestamp is


   function Calculate_Ada_Timestamp( Timestamp_Value : in Time_Types.Timestamp_Time_Type )
    return Ada.Calendar.Time;



  procedure Put_Timestamp
    (Timestamp: in Time_Types.Timestamp_Record_Type);

end Timestamp;
```

At first I thought the error must mean that Put_Timestamp, with a parameter of type Timestamp_Record_Type did not exist, but according to the above code, this clearly is not the case.

What am I missing?

Comment: I agree with Keith that you're overusing the name `Timestamp`.  In the body of `Put_Timestamp`, for instance, you have a parameter named `Timestamp`, and that will hide the package name `Timestamp`.  If you're in that situation and you need to get the package name back, you can use `Standard.Timestamp`, which will find a top-level definition of `Timestamp` (i.e. a library package, procedure, or function name, that is not a child of some other package).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> no selector "Put_Timestamp" for **type** "Timestamp_Record_Type" defined at time_types.ads:99

(emphasis added.)

You've shown us a declaration of `Timestamp` as a package, but the compiler apparently thinks that `Timestamp` is an expression (presumably a variable name) of type `Timestamp_Record_Type`.

Somewhere in code that you haven't shown us, I think you've declared a variable named `Timestamp` of type `Timestamp_Record_Type`, and the compiler is looking for a `.Put_Timestamp` that can be applied to something of that type.

I suggest that you're over-using the name `Timestamp`; you use the same name for the parameter of the `Put_Timestamp` procedure. Perhaps `Timestamps` would be a better name for the package.